# Dojo DateTime does not show correct time in XPages

Tags: xpages

When i used djTimeTextBox in XPages but it does not show the correct time. TimeZone settings of Domino Server is fine because When i save the document It's saved correctly(02.12.2017 17:00:00 ZE3) but it shows one hour before in Xpages form. I do not know how to solve this problem. I tried to solve it with ComputedField It show as is. I am having problem with Dojo Object..

//Dojo Object

```
<xe:djTimeTextBox id="endTime_1" value="#{document1.endTime}">
</xe:djTimeTextBox>

<xp:text escape="true" id="endTime_2" value="#{document1.endTime}">
<xp:this.converter><xp:convertDateTime type="time" ignoreUserTimeZone="true" timeZone="Etc/GMT-3" timeStyle="short"></xp:convertDateTime></xp:this.converter></xp:text>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems it is off by DLS - Dojo object possibly have no date part so it ignores DLS. Your converter ignores it explicitly, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in 8.5.3 look at this
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO79805
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO71280
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=12C120AE9296BEAD852576560044ACE1#mobileViewer

Comment: I am using 9.0.1